# SMTP Authentication Error "Failure Sendng Mail"

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I am trying to send email from my asp.net web page if certain conditions are fulfilled.

Here is my code.

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
NetworkCredential basicCredential = 
    new NetworkCredential("username", "password"); 
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(); 
MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@yourdomain.com"); 

smtpClient.Host = "mail.mydomain.com";
smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtpClient.Credentials = basicCredential;

message.From = fromAddress;
message.Subject = "your subject";
//Set IsBodyHtml to true means you can send HTML email.
message.IsBodyHtml = true;
message.Body = "<h1>your message body</h1>";
message.To.Add("to@anydomain.com"); 

try
{
    smtpClient.Send(message);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Error, could not send the message
    Response.Write(ex.Message);
}
```

I have not shared the server details. I'm trying to send it from my outlook email address. However, I keep getting an error: ***Failure sending mail***.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 25);

    smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("youremailid@gmail.com", "yourPassword");
    smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();


    //Setting From , To and CC
    mail.From = new MailAddress("fromemailid@gmail.com", "MyWeb Site");
    mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("toemailid@gmail.com"));
    mail.CC.Add(new MailAddress("ccemailid@gmail.com"));
    mail.Subject = "your subject";
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.Body = "<h1>your message body</h1>";

    smtpClient.Send(mail);
```

thanks,

Comment: The site is still on development server of asp.net

Comment: so for testing just pass the gmail or any other emial server like yahoo or live

Comment: I am getting an error that "unable to connect to the remote server"

Comment: SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587); change this

Comment: make this changes its just for changing smtp port gmail smtp port is 587

Comment: let me know if any problem

Comment: The operation has timed out.

Comment: smtpClient.Timeout =  20000; use this your timeout will extent of make it larger then 20000 and if its not work then change the port 587 to 465

Comment: Unable to connect to the remote server

Answer (score 0):

For sending mail you can't use your development server port.

You have to use the smtp server port of your mail server.

for smtp.live.com you should use either port `25 or 587`

For this code below, specify VALID login details `(email/password)`

```
client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(
            @"email_account",
            @"email_password");
```

Comment: So what changes do I have to make to make it compatible for IIS