# Send SMTP Mail Error: The transport failed to connect to the server

Tags: c#, asp.net, email

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage();
        Msg.From = txtFrom.Text;
        Msg.To = txtTo.Text;
        Msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
        Msg.Body = txtBody.Text;
        SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "1.20.72.1";
        SmtpMail.Send(Msg);
        Msg = null;
        Page.RegisterStartupScript("UserMsg", "<script>alert('Mail sent thank you...');if (alert) {window.location='SendMail.aspx';}</Script>");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        msgLabel.Text = "Caught Exception." + ex;
    }
}
```

Help Me in above click `Send` i am Getting Error like This

Caught

```
Exception.System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): The transport failed to connect to the server. 
---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. 
---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The transport failed to connect to the server. 
--- End of inner exception stack trace --- 
at System.RuntimeType.InvokeDispMethod(String name, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Object target, Object[] args, Boolean[] byrefModifiers, Int32 culture, String[] namedParameters) 
at System.RuntimeType.InvokeMember(String name, BindingFlags bindingFlags, Binder binder, Object target, Object[] providedArgs, ParameterModifier[] modifiers, CultureInfo culture, String[] namedParams) 
at System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.LateBoundAccessHelper.CallMethod(Object obj, String methodName, Object[] args) 
at System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.LateBoundAccessHelper.CallMethod(Object obj, String methodName, Object[] args) 
at System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.CdoSysHelper.Send(MailMessage message) at System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.Send(MailMessage message) 
at MaiApp.Mail.btnSubmit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Riffaz\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MaiApp\MaiApp\Mail.aspx.cs:line 28
```

Comment: It says: `The transport failed to connect to the server.` Can you ping the smtp server or connect to it in another way?

Comment: Is SMTP Server installed, and running ?

Comment: have you tried use the alternative: System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient, if it yields same or similar error (connection issue), then either your smtp server is not available or it's locked down to allow designated clients to send smtp emails

Comment: if your server doesn't require authentication (and it looks like it doesn't), then it probably doesn't have your username set up for authenticated access - hence the failed connection.

Comment: Try specifying the port.

Comment: I am not sure that the obsolete class SmtpClient can accept a SmtpServer property expressed as an IP address. Have you tried (if possible) with a dns name?

Comment: take look to the following post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20769236/smtp-authentication-error-failure-sendng-mail/20769647#20769647

Answer (score 1):

In the documentation on SmtpMail property [SmtpServer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mail.smtpmail.smtpserver%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the MSDN says

> Gets or sets the name of the SMTP relay mail server to use to send
>   e-mail messages.

Instead, for the new SmtpClient class, in the [description of the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0y6s613%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it says

> A String that contains the name or IP address of the host computer
>   used for SMTP transactions.

So I would try to call

```
try 
{
    MailAddress from = new MailAddress(txtFrom.Text);
    MailAddress to = new MailAddress(txtTo.Text);
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);
    message.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
    message.Body = txtBody.Text;
    SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("1.20.72.1");
    client.Send(message);
}
catch (Exception ex) 
{
    msgLabel.Text = "Caught Exception." + ex;
}
```

This code will use the default port 25 for the SMTP traffic, if this is not correct then you need to configure the correct port for the SMTP traffic.
There are other concerns in your code. For example you don't provide any credentials to the SMTP Server. This seems a bit strange nowadays where few services trust an anonymous user.